# Displaying data from different tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Have researched extensively eloquent relationships and laravel all afternoon and can't seem to find a solution.

I have a transaction table displaying User IDs in the From and To columns. I want to show the users emails that correspond to their IDs.

Here is my relationships:

Transaction model:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'email');
    }
```

User model:

```
public function transaction()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Transaction);
    }
```

And heres the code from the controller. However I KNOW this just returns ALL the transactions. But I really can't find how I would display the emails instead of the IDs:

```
public function index()
{
    $table = Table::create(Transaction::get());
    return view('table', compact('table'));
}
```

Comment: can you explain the  `$table = Table::create(Transaction::get());` line?

Comment: Thats purely the code I was using to display ALL transactions. It relates to the $table declaration I was using in my view:
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    {!! $table->render() !!}
</div>
@endsection

Comment: i don't understand...

Comment: just follow the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent and you should be fine, what you do in `index` is a little bit strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try to get transactions with related model (user) or with join to users table?

```
$transactions = Transaction::query()->with(['user'])->get();
$table = Table::create(Transaction::get());
$table->addColumn('email', 'E-mail', function($model) {
return $model->user->email;
});
return view('table', compact('table'));
```

Comment: Whilst waiting for a reply I managed to knock up something similar to this. My problem was I was trying to render a table with a lazy one liner. I have some more work to do.